# Not Able Increase My Counter Sequentially Inside xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Objective is to get the count of all the siblings and then inside the loop print the contents of all the siblings by referring to their index; below is the code section

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <xsl:variable name="headerCount">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(xPath/To/My/Item)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="count" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
    
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="xPath/To/My/Item[$count]/ItemVal"/>
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="$count+number(1)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="xPath/To/My/Item[$count]/ItemVal"/>
        </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

This code section is working fine and rendering the contents accordingly from index[1] and [2] from the `<Item><ItemVal>Content</ItemVal></Item>.....<Item>...</Item>`

**Note:** Indexes rather number of siblings can be more than 2

But when I am trying to run that inside a xsl:for-each and xsl:if test it is not working below is the code snippet :

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <xsl:variable name="headerCount">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(xPath/To/My/Item)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="count" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
    
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:for-each select="xPath/To/My/Item">
            <xsl:if test="$count &lt;= number($headerItemCount)">
                <xsl:value-of select="xPath/To/My/Item[$count]/ItemVal"/>
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="$count+number(1)"/>               
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

Where it went wrong any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<xsl:variable name="headerCount">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(xPath/To/My/Item)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="count" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>

<fo:block>
    <xsl:for-each select="xPath/To/My/Item">
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $headerCount">
            <xsl:value-of select="ItemVal"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like rather procedural thinking to want to have a loop counter; there is no need to, you can process your sequence (XSLT 2/3) or node-set (XSLT 1) selected just fine with a single for-each or apply-templates e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="xPath/To/My/Item[position() &lt;= count(xPath/To/My/HeaderItem)]">`.

If you want to store the count of a sequence or node-set in a variable, that is of course possible, but take note that using `<xsl:variable name="headerCount" select="count(xPath/To/My/Item)"/>` is both much more natural and efficient than your nested `xsl:variable/xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Do need to use any specific name space for position() function to get work?

Comment: @RitoSarkar, no, I tried to use the names/paths from your sample, only used `HeaderItem` in one place instead of the original as otherwise the sample in the question seemed to use the same two paths anyway.